# Postgres and PostGis , can not create extension

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have installed postgresql 9.4 and postgis 2.1.5, and also dependecies.
But when I fire in my terminal:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis; CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;" test_base
```

I get:

> ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/postgis-2.1.so": liblwgeom-2.1.5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

which tells me that I'm missing something, after some googling around I have not found any solution :(

Is someone have experience with this?

Comment: It means that the extensions (.so libraries) have not been installed, so you cannot enable them. (they should live in the same directory as the postgres libs)

Comment: How did you install the components? On what OS?

Comment: @dzordz Did you find a solution to your problem? If so, please share it here.

Comment: When you say you "installed" them, how did you do so? Build from source? Have you added /usr/local/lib to your /etc/ld.so.conf paths?

Comment: Run "find / -name liblwgeom-2.1.5.so" and see where the library actually is.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Ubuntu 14.04 with postgresql 9.4

I reinstalled postgis and this solved the problem:

```
apt-get install postgis
```